# Is there an option to download file from Google drive without using Google Drive API?

Tags: android, file, download, mime-types, android-download-manager

I am developing an application which is downloading a file by clicking a button which has been wired with the google drive file url. I am able to download the file using download manager by providing a filename and extension(mimetype) from the user input.

Now, what I want to do is download the file using the file url starting with `"docs.google.com/..."` and give them the **metadata(name and mimetype)** they had when they were uploaded.

Any way to do it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/examples/

Comment: Google doesn't allow such a download. Even though you provide a downloadable public link it will through some token error.